# Mongoose can't query out of Mongo, but shell can

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Mongo crashes out of nowhere. It seems like the entire database has been dropped. Luckily, the .0 and .ns files remain, so I create a mongodump and mongorestore that. It seems like everything is fine, I can query for documents using the shell. But the app still couldn't query anything out of it, so I tried to add a doc into the database (using the app), and it worked. So I know that it can communicate with Mongo.

The only query that seems to work is the one with no query parameter.

```
PendingPasta.findOne(function(err, pasta){
    if (err) throw err;
    else{
        res.send(pasta);
    }
});
```

The other ones that have conditions don't seem to work at all. What is going on?

Comment: maybe collections fields have changed/different.So for query with conditions it will show error.

Comment: I don't think that's it. I haven't changed the schema at all. The fields are exactly the same and I can query for them. I'm starting to think this is a mongo thing, since I've just copied the database over to my PC, and it works perfectly fine here.

Comment: is the `PendingPasta` the model ?.Then maybe check findOne() method, is there any conditions parameter passing? or the postion of condition parameter.